# Disable Cassandra TDE after enabling the key creation

Tags: cassandra

Is there a way to disable TDE once enabled in DSE 6.7.7 version ?

We have already followed the steps from https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/6.7/security/secEncryptEnable.html

But we would like to revert the key creation and disable TDE on the tables. What happens to the existing data once we disable the TDE will we be able to query that data without any issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just ALTER TABLE to change the "WITH COMPRESSION" settings and remove the encryption that was previously configured.
After that, run "nodetool upgradesstables -a keyspace table".